# Android studio emulator automatically starts if no device connected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I dont want to run my app on emulator but in case of loose cable it get started every time. its very frustrating. Is there any way to stop this behaviour without deleting the Emulator.

Comment: first of all, u don't need a cable to run the app on the emulator, whenever u connect to the real device then and then u need a cable. About which cable you are talking about??